# Angular2 - .post( ) / .put( ) not working

Tags: angular

Trying to make a angular2 .post( )/.put( ) call, but nothing comes in backend. No errors, nothing. Seems the call just die

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

let body = JSON.stringify(this.user);
    let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return new Promise( ( resolve ) => {
        this.http.post( this.LOGIN_URL, body, options )
            .map( ( res ) => res.json() )
            .subscribe(
                ( data ) => resolve(data),
                ( error ) => resolve(error)
            );
        });
```

When i change to .get( ) / .delete( ) i receive the call on node backend, so, works fine:

```
this.http.get( this.LOGIN_URL ) 
this.http.delete( this.LOGIN_URL )
```

What is wrong with my .post( ) / .put( ) calls?

Comment: Assuming nothing is null (e.g. `this.user`, `this.LOGIN_URL`), nothing appears to be wrong with your code, from what I can see. That all looks fine. What does your backend route look like?

Comment: @justin.m.chase
I have a node server to get the requests.
When i perform a Delete, for example, i receive normally:

`::ffff:192.168.1.1 - - [18/Jul/2016:20:09:16 +0000] "DELETE /login HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "okhttp/3.2.0"`

For post/put requests nothing happen =/

Comment: Are you using express? You very well could have one of your routes misconfigured.

Comment: @justin.m.chase
`var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.delete('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});`

most simple as possible

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I've been seeing a bug with ng2 and sending data in the body that's not a string. I realize you're stringifying the object but the header is making it break, I think.

Comment: All `http` calls return an observable. Are you sure you don't have to call `subscribe` on them before calling `map`?

Comment: Any answer here?

Comment: Solve here : need to subscribe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381200/angular-2-http-get-not-getting