# Angular 2 Http.get not responding

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using Http.get to retrieve a configuration file. I've done this many times with success, but this time nothing. I'm not seeing the trace in my console, and I'm not seeing an error either, even though I am using .catch. What might be my problem here?

```
this._http.get('./assets/dashboard/json/config.json')
  .map((response: Response) => {

    console.log(response.json());

  })
  .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'Server error'));
```

Comment: you have to subscribe this in order to fire the `http.get()` method

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/41381200/3001761

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 http get not getting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381200/angular-2-http-get-not-getting)

Comment: Pit of success, eh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have **`subscribe()`** in order to recieve the data

```
   this._http.get('./assets/dashboard/json/config.json')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
          data => this.ResResponse= data,
          err => this.logError(err),
          () => console.log('Completed')
        ); 

    logError(err) {
      console.error('There was an error: ' + err);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you fix this example so it is working. Then I may select it as the correct answer. Also, I would like to add a 'catch' as well. Where would I do that.

Answer (score 2):

you need to call subscribe() in order that the request is executed.