# Unable to hit web api. Not even able to get error

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Trying to hit a WEB API through Angular http post method but unable to hit the web api and catch block is not throwing any error as well. I have enabled cross-origin policy as well.
When I paste the web api url in th browser then it hits the method but not through angular http post function.

Below is the code component code

```
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });  

    this._http.post(this._commonUrl, filter, options)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);


     private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
     }
```

Controller code

```
[RoutePrefix("api/common")]
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
    public ProductController()
    {

    }

    [Route("initialize")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage SearchLazada(Filter filter)
    {
        try
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 http get not getting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381200/angular-2-http-get-not-getting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post request will not be even raised. Look in the network calls.

- You need to subscribe to it.

  ```
  this._http.post(this._commonUrl, filter, options)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError)
      .subscribe(data =>console.log(data));
  ```
- You can use the error call back to access the error

  ```
  this._http.post(this._commonUrl, filter, options)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError)
      .subscribe(data =>console.log(data),
      (error)=>console.log(error));//////////////////////////
  ```

Answer (score 0):

With Content-Type : application/json , you should transform body data to json.

filter : JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: Oh yes I am already doing that in a step above which I didn't paste in the question...