# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined using D3 Bar Chart in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

Cannot read property 'map' of undefined when i map the totalStores object.

I have parsed the existing JSON data into two variables store and storeCount, store object for X-Axis and storeCount for Y-Axis

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.DashboardService.getActiveProjectsStatusByDimension(
      this.statusIndex,
      this.dimension
    ).subscribe(res => {
      this.res = res;
      this.projectSelectedDimension = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));

      this.totalStores = Array();

      var storeCountIndex = 2;

      for (let k = 0; k < this.projectSelectedDimension.data.length; k++) {
        let obj = this.projectSelectedDimension.data[k];
        let xAxis = Object.keys(obj)[0];
        let yAxis = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]][storeCountIndex];
        // console.log("x:", xAxis);
        // console.log("y:", yAxis);
        let objBarChart = { store: xAxis, storeCount: yAxis };
        this.totalStores.push(objBarChart);
      }

    });

    this.initAxis();
  }


private initAxis() {
    this.x = d3Scale
      .scaleBand()
      .rangeRound([0, this.width])
      .padding(0.1);
    this.y = d3Scale.scaleLinear().rangeRound([this.height, 0]);
    this.x.domain(this.totalStores.map(d => d.store));
    this.y.domain([
      0,
      d3Array.max(this.totalStores, this.totalStores.map(d => d.storeCount))   // erroe saying valueof is not a function
    ]);
  }
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373225/angular-7-error-type-error-cannot-read-property-map-of-undefined/56374388#56374388

Comment: I think `totalStores` is `undefined` because it is initialized (through ` this.totalStores = Array();`) only when `subscribe` callback is executed: `initAxis` is invoked immediatly after `subscribe` invocation... try to invoke `initAxis` at the end of subscribtion body, e.g. after  the `for` loop...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is .subscribe in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921788/what-is-subscribe-in-angular)

Comment: No it not the duplicate of any question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code inside the .subscribe() function runs AFTER the getActiveProjectsStatusByDimension() function returns. So you are trying to map over an undefined object. To solve this, simply put your initAxis() function inside the subscribe block.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.DashboardService.getActiveProjectsStatusByDimension(
      this.statusIndex,
      this.dimension
    ).subscribe(res => {
      this.res = res;
      this.projectSelectedDimension = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));

      this.totalStores = Array();

      var storeCountIndex = 2;

      for (let k = 0; k < this.projectSelectedDimension.data.length; k++) {
        let obj = this.projectSelectedDimension.data[k];
        let xAxis = Object.keys(obj)[0];
        let yAxis = obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]][storeCountIndex];
        // console.log("x:", xAxis);
        // console.log("y:", yAxis);
        let objBarChart = { store: xAxis, storeCount: yAxis };
        this.totalStores.push(objBarChart);
      }
      this.initAxis() //put it here
    });

//    this.initAxis();
  }
```

Comment: Accept the answer then. Glad to help.

Comment: Hi @dijolf, map of undefined error is gone, now facing the error saying " valueof is not a function" in initAxis() function, check the updated code with comment where the error is coming