# Get First Index in Array Object Type Scripts

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to get index zero record from Array  Object **dataList** in the below code snippet. I am new to JavaScript and Typescript.

```
dataList: Array<any> = [];
 data: any;

 constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {  


   this.apiService.getEncounterDashBoard(this.searchCond)
     .subscribe(data => {
       this.dataList = data.result;
     });

    let labels = this.dataList[0];
}
```

Comment: Put the line `let labels = this.dataList[0];` just after `this.dataList = data.result;`. The reason is `dataList` is updated asynchronously in a callback, meaning `this.dataList[0]` might not hold any data when you call it.

Comment: `.subscribe` is an async function. You will have to set `labels` inside `.subscribe`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is .subscribe in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921788/what-is-subscribe-in-angular)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this

```
dataList: Array<any> = [];
 data: any;

 constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {  

 let labels = [];
   this.apiService.getEncounterDashBoard(this.searchCond)
     .subscribe(data => {
       this.dataList = data.result;
       labels = this.dataList[0]; 
// here you can see that we are access the data inside the subscription block bcs javascript is asynchronous. So it is not wait complete the api call 
     });
}
```

Comment: you should declare labels outside of the subscribe block, otherwise it can only be used inside.

Answer (score 0):

Think of async operations as those that occur after the rest.
Your `getEncounterDashBoard` is called and starts the request, but everything in your code continues, with or without response (usually without as everything is too quick).

Therefore, your `let labels` is trying to get `this.dataList[0]` before you actually have a response. One thing you can do, is create a component-scoped variable `labels`, and then asign it inside the callback of the async function (inside the `subscribe`), this way this happens after the async function has resolved.

Another option, is create a function that handles the logic you want to happen after the async is resolved, and call it inside the `subscribe`.

```
afterDataList() {
  let labels = this.dataList[0]
  // do something with it
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the line inside the `subscribe` function.

```
.subscribe(data => {
   this.dataList = data.result;
   let labels = this.dataList[0];
 });
```

You can also use ES6 destructuring:

```
.subscribe(data => {
   this.dataList = data.result;
   let [labels] = this.dataList;
 });
```