# Angular: I need help loading text file data into a string

Tags: angular, text-files

I am reading data from a text file, and the reading of data works fine, and I can even console.log the data. But I am confused on how I can transfer the data into a variable. Here is my code currently:

```
let mazeData; //need to get this variable to equal to the 'data' in the code below

    this.httpClient.get('assets/Maze1.txt', { responseType: 'text' })
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: `.subscribe(data => mazeData = data)` Now you'll probably say it doesn't work because when you log `mazeData` you get nothing in the console. And then you'll face the arduous task of wrapping your head around asynchronous execution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
this.httpClient.get('assets/Maze1.txt', { responseType: 'text' })
      .subscribe(data => mazeData = data);
```

I suggest you read up more on subscribe.
This answer might explain things more simply to you:
[what is .subscribe in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44921788/what-is-subscribe-in-angular/44921830)