# How to write service in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-http, angular-components

My Component:

```
getDetailsByPhone(phone: any) {
        this.phoneSearchDetails = this.appService.manageHttp('get', 'search?number='+phone, '');
 }
```

My service:

```
manageHttp(method: any, url: any, body: any) {
    this.headers = this.config.setHeaders();
    var urlto = this.config.serverUrl +''+url;

    return  this.http.get(urlto,{ headers: this.headers }).map((response: Response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

With this code I am not able to see the response going in network.I am not sure about whats wrong and I didnt see any error in console.Can anyone please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 http get not getting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381200/angular-2-http-get-not-getting)

Answer (score 1):

You must subscribe to the observable or it won't fire since it's lazy:

```
this.appService.manageHttp('get', 'search?number='+phone, '').subscribe((res) => {

  this.phoneSearchDetails = res;

  console.log(res);
}, (err) => {
  // handle error
});
```

Also as you can see I assign the value of `phoneSearchDetails` inside the callback of the `subscribe` since you can't return anything from a `subscribe`.