# Angular 2 consecutive http requests

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-http, angular-observable

In my angular data service I am trying to make two http request, with the second request depending on data from the first request.  The first request is working fine, but for some reason the second request is never hitting my backend server.  I was hoping if someone can tell me if I am doing this correctly or show me what I am doing wrong.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor( private http: Http ) { }

public twoRequest() {
    this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/1st_request`).subscribe((data) => 
      this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/2nd_request`, {data: data}))
}
```

edit: I didn't subscribe to the second request.  I didn't know you have to subscribe to each request you make even if they are in the same block of code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 http get not getting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381200/angular-2-http-get-not-getting)

Comment: Its a little different since I am doing two calls in the same block. I think this question would be useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` to the `http.post` also. It will never do a request if you don't `subscribe` to it.

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor( private http: Http ) { }

  public twoRequest() {
     this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/1st_request`).subscribe((data) => 
       this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/2nd_request`, {data: data}).subscribe(/*...*/));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public twoRequest() {
        this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/1st_request`).subscribe((data) => {
            this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/2nd_request`, {data:data})) 
               .subscribe((resp: any) => {
                 console.log(resp)
             })
           }

    }
```

Comment: there is no dependency on curly braces, he hasn't subscribed on the second post. Correctly pointed out by @suren