# Implement properly list of Objects from rest api

Tags: spring, angular, typescript

I want to implement Angular example which gets list from rest API. I tried this:

SQL query:

```
    @Override
    public Iterable<Merchants> findAll() {
        String hql = "select e from " + Merchants.class.getName() + " e";
        TypedQuery<Merchants> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Merchants.class);
        List<Merchants> merchants = query.getResultList();
        return merchants;
    }
```

Rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/merchants")
public class MerchantController {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public Iterable<Merchants> getMerchantsList() {
        return merchantRepository
                .findAll();
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MerchantService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }    
  getList() {
    return this.http.get("...../api/merchants/list");
  }
}
```

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-terminal',
  templateUrl: './terminal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./terminal.component.scss']
})
export class TerminalComponent implements OnInit {
  merchants: Merchant[];
  constructor(private merchantService: MerchantService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }   

  ngOnInit() {               
    this.merchantService.getList();
  }    
}
```

But when I lock the component via web page nothing happens. Can you give me some advice where I'm wrong?
Probably my typescript is somewhere incorrect?

Comment: You need to call `subscribe` on the `Observable`, otherwise it won't make the HTTP request

Comment: Can you show me complete example please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 http get not getting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381200/angular-2-http-get-not-getting)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `subscribe` on the `Observable`, otherwise it won't make the HTTP request

```
ngOnInit() {               
  this.merchantService.getList().subscribe(res => {
    console.log("The response is", res); 
  });
}
```