# HttpClient doesn't make http network request

Tags: angular

I am using HttpClient and it doesn't make a network request, there are no errors so I don't know what is wrong.

```
  postFile(file: FileUpload) {
    console.log('posting file');
    return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + '/api/file', file, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError('postFile', []))
      );
  }
```

app.module

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
// ...
imports: [
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```

Comment: You don't subscribe to your observable.

Comment: @matt have subscribe you api call on component?

Comment: Where are you *calling* this method? Please give a [mcve]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 http get not getting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41381200/angular-2-http-get-not-getting)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `subscribe()`.

```
return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + '/api/file', file, this.httpOptions)
   .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('postFile', []))
   )
   .subscribe();
```

or in your component call the method like this:

```
this.postFile(file).subscribe();
```